# How to make select query using IN condition with unknown number of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have two dropdownlist one for project and 2nd for category.
I have a to select ddproject  where i get id, based on this id i have to populate ddcategory.
Table Sturcture [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/682f6/4)

Here simple query if i select ProjectOne from my dropdownlist

```
select  id,name from tbcategory where id in(1,2)
```

But my problem is i don't know how many value will be there in the `in` condition.

C#:
1st i split column name `categoryid` and get values later what to do am confused.
Also let me know whether am doing in right way or any other alernative way to achive this

**Edited:**
Or should i change my table structure, if yes then what schema to be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your data, there is a many : many relationship between Category and Project. You therefore need to model another Many:Many table to hold data modelling this relationship.

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b434/3)

Firstly, create a new table to hold the Many:Many relationship between Category and Project:

```
create table tbProjectCategory
(
  tbProjectId INT,
  tbCategoryId INT
);
```

Then, remove the string comma delimited relationship in tbProject - this isn't useful. Instead, insert the links into the Many Many table. e.g.:

```
insert into tbProjectCategory(tbProjectId, tbCategoryId) values (1, 1), (1, 2);
```

Will link project 1 to category 1 and 2.

Then, to find all the Categories for Project 1, you need to join through the Many:Many link table, filtering by the Project Id:

```
select  cat.id, cat.name 
  from tbcategory cat
  inner join tbProjectCategory prjcat
  on prjcat.tbCategoryId = cat.id
  where prjCat.tbProjectId = 1;
```

I've also removed your identity column for brevity's sake - it makes it easier to know which data records are linked.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but can you explain it more am still not clear about it,

Comment: Sir but here one project can have more then one category, so have to insert each category record for one project,

Comment: That's exactly the point of a many : many table. Category `Hardware` is used by both ProjectOne and ProjectTwo. The category is created just the once, as is the project, however, a record is added to the link table for each valid association between Project and Category.

Comment: @SuartLC : Thank you, am going with your annswer

Answer (score 3):

I would create M:N relationship table like:

```
tbProjects2Categories
    IDCategory int;
    IDProject int;
```

Then you can make query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name FROM tbCategory c JOIN tbProjects2Categories pc 
                ON c.IDCategory = pc.IDCategory 
                WHERE pc.IDProject = @selectedProjectId;
```

Than relations between projects and categories will look like:

> ### IDProject | IDCategory
>
> ```
>      1     |    1
>      1     |    2
>      1     |    3
>      2     |    1
>      2     |    3
> ```

And it means in your original schema:

```
(1,'ProjectOne','Mumbai','1,2,3'); 
(2,'ProjectTwo','USA','1,3');
```

*To complete the answer:*

Storing entity relationships in comma-separated lists is not really a good practice. You would even have hard days to split that column value and make your query work.

Comment: Thank you for reply, so i need to create a new table where i can save both table ids, There is posible of redundent data for each category respected project id have to inserted

Comment: If you do not want to have duplicit combinations of [IDProject, IDCategory] just let `IDCategory` and `IDProject` to be composite primary key. If duplicities are allowed add and Identity primary key such `IDProjects2Cats` to that table -> but in this case you will also have duplicities in your query result so you should add DISTINCT to the query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, comma-separated values are not a good way to store relationships in a database.  You should create one more table to define the relationships between the two original tables:

```
create table tbProjectCategory (id int IDENTITY(1,1),projectId int, categoryId int)
```

Then you can query it based on projectId like this:

```
select * from tbcategory c
  inner join tbProjectCategory pc on c.id = pc.categoryId
where projectId = 1;
```

Please try this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b11acb/2

Comment: Thank you for the reply, +1 for sql fiddle demo